# Issue deploying Asp.Net MVC 4 website to Azure

Tags: deployment, azure, asp.net-mvc-4

How do you deploy your website in Azure so that it looks exactly like when you run it in your localhost? This is a very simple website that I created following the ASP.NET MVC4  tutorials. However, I added a new background image and it doesn't show. Is there anything else I need to do to make sure all of my files are being deployed?

Here is the code that "should" be on my site. This is the pone in my solution.

```
 <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
 <title>LOTUS Marketing Solutions</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
 <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/Site.css" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.jcarousel.setup.js"></script>
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
 </head>
```

this is what I "actually" showing on the site view source code

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home Page - LOTUS Marketing Solutions</title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="/Content/css?v=Zxt_kvPMVcEtaCRbYJCSpGOy25BUARXyn8EetggjSF01" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=qVODBytEBVVePTNtSFXgRX0NCEjh9U_Oj8ePaSiRcGg1"></script>

  </head>
```

clearly, something is wrong. The  contents are not remotely alike!

I was able to pull this out

**CA0058 Error Running Code Analysis CA0058 : The referenced assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' could not be found. This assembly is required for analysis and was referenced by: C:\Users\lotusms\Desktop\LOTUS MARKETING\ASP.NET\WebsiteManager\WebsiteManager\bin\WebsiteManager.dll, C:\Users\lotusms\Desktop\LOTUS MARKETING\ASP.NET\WebsiteManager\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth.2.0.20710.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.dll. [Errors and Warnings] (Global)**

**CA0001 Error Running Code Analysis CA0001 : The following error was encountered while reading module 'Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth': Assembly reference cannot be resolved: DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246. [Errors and Warnings] (Global)**

Could this have something to do with the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC4 uploading files](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/198142/asp-net-mvc4-uploading-files)

Comment: re: your edit - Come on dude, I just explained below why they are different!

Comment: I know, I mean, look at other things like the meta charset tag or even the title. That is the way the original template <head> is designed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *should* just work assuming your project solution is correct.

Make sure the file is actually included in the solution (Show all files, right click, include in project).

View the source, is the image tag you have used at least in the HTML?

How are you deploying it?
What output is there in Visual Studio when you do a deploy?

Or are you packaging then uploading on the Azure Management website? Make sure you are uploading the correct package. You may have changed build configuration (built under Release for example) then when you try to upload the package, the Azure wbesite File,Open windows is still defaulted to your packaged debug folder.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As you can see I am a noob in ASP.NET. This is only the first tutorial. But to answer your question, this is what the code is linking to for styleshhet:

      <link href="/Content/css?v=Zxt_kvPMVcEtaCRbYJCSpGOy25BUARXyn8EetggjSF01" rel="stylesheet"/>

It should be:

<link href="/Content/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

What did I do?

Comment: you do have a lot to learn :-) This is what the CSS link looks like once it's bundled. Copy and paste that odd looking URL into your browser (after the root domain) and you should be able to download your minified CSS

Comment: I clicked on it and to open it and it showed the css file in a compressed form with no white spaces. No download options tho. What am I supposed to do then? Copy and paste it over the original css file in my VS and re-publish?

Comment: I was just pointing out that the link URL is not an error. Forget the image and CSS for now. Is any textual change on your site being published?

Comment: Yes, the actual content is fine. Menus work, functionality was not altered, only the look. (background, logo, site colors, fonts, etc...) If I could post a screenshot I would

Comment: is your new image referenced anywhere in the CSS of the azure deployed site?

Comment: I just searched for .col2, .col2 a{color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#ae0759;} which is in the new css and its not in the deployed site css

Comment: pretty difficult to figure why it is not deploying, did you do it via visual studio, or packaging it then uploading via azure management website like I asked in my question?

Comment: Through Visual Studio 12, per tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: I added more info to the problem in an edit